# Connecting knockoutjs to an already populated DOM element

Tags: knockout.js

I'm working on a page which is being server from an ASP.NET MVC3 app that I want to use KnockoutJS in.

On the View I'm getting passed a populated Model (which I'm converting to a KnockoutJS viewModel) and I want to build up some of the DOM server-side. This seems logical since I already have the objects there to generate the initial HTML and it'll provide a better experience to the users as there wont be a delay between the page load and the DOM population (it also means I have basic functionality for non-JavaScript clients).

After doing some research I'm assuming I need to create a custom `bindingHandler` so I created this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serverForEach = {
    init: function() { /* no-op */ },
    update: function() {
        //call off to the built in loop handler
    }
};
```

So my thinking was that I create a handler which does nothing in the `init` phase (as the DOM is already populated) and in the `update` phase I'll just insert the new value. I'd like to leverage the built-in templating so this can be a generic solution as well.

The problem is that everything falls apart in this scenario. If the `init` does nothing then the `update` fails as the bindingContext that comes in as the last argument seems wrong, and if I include the init it'll destroy the existing HTML.

Anyone tried this/ know what I should do to support this scenario or is it just too far removed from what you can/ should do?

Also, I don't want to have a separate DOM element for the server generated HTML than the Knockout HTML.

Answer (score 8):

I think I understand what your problem is. You are wanting to populate the markup initially for non-js users and simply overwrite it when binding to KO.

For simple bindings like text this is not an issue simply include the data-bind attribute in the markup from the server or include at runtime and away you go. For the template foreach binding things are a little more difficult since it will append values when bound.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4f9N2/4/) that describes the above scenario and demonstrates the solution below. It's a little basic but should get you started.

The basic idea is to clear the element on init and then delegate the rest to the existing template binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serverForEach = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // clear the list first
        $(element).children().remove();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ko.bindingHandlers['template'].update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs this to work for knockout.js 2.0+ (note the `bindingContext` in update)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.serverForEach = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).children().remove();
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init(element, valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    }
};
```